# Error in ls.cc file?

Tags: ns2

While installing I am getting follwing error

In file included from `linkstate/ls.cc:67:0:`

```
linkstate/ls.h: In instantiation of ‘void LsMap<Key, T>::eraseAll() [with Key = int; T = LsIdSeq]’:
linkstate/ls.cc:396:28:   required from here
linkstate/ls.h:137:58: error: ‘erase’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
  void eraseAll() { erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
                                                          ^
linkstate/ls.h:137:58: note: declarations in dependent base ‘std::map<int, LsIdSeq, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, LsIdSeq> > >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
linkstate/ls.h:137:58: note: use ‘this->erase’ instead
```

`make: *** [linkstate/ls.o] Error 1`

Ns make failed!

I am working on a NS2 project . Got struck at installation 
please help

Answer (score 5):

Open the file ls.cc (in my case, it was ls.h) in `ns-2.xx/linkstate` directory. Change the 137th line ie. as follows from

```
    void eraseAll() { erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
```

to

```
    void eraseAll() {baseMap::erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
```

Comment: I prefer this solution: using basemap instead of 'this' (that is also suggested by the build output) looks better in this context.

Answer (score 1):

its just simple. you need to change "erase" to "this->erase" in linkstate/ls.h:137:58 file. then try installing again.